# What does Perl's modifier /m = multiline mean?

Tags: perl

what does Perl's /m modifier means from this example?

For example, let say I have the following information in the Example.txt text file. And each line ends with the newline character with a data record of **Data**
The input record separator is set to:

```
 $/="__Data__";

 Example.txt

 __Data__
 This is test A.\n
 This is test B.\n
 This is test C.\n
 This is test D.\n
```

Question 1, after changing the input record separator to **Data**, would the ^ and $ characters be position as follow?

```
  ^__Data__
  This is test A.\n
  This is test B.\n
  This is test C.\n
  This is test D.\n$
```

Question 2, let say I use the /m modifier while having the input record separator still set to **Data**, would the ^ and $ characters be set to the following?

```
  ^__Data__$
  ^This is test A.\n$
  ^This is test B.\n$
  ^This is test C.\n$
  ^This is test D.\n$

  if(/__Data__/m)
  {
      print;
  }
```

Comment: Have you experimented with this in Perl?

Comment: Yes but I'm not clear on how to test the positions of ^ and $. Using thi forum to help clear up my understanding.

Comment: An editor cleaning up this question and title would help the new user not get downvoted for what turned out to be an interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/$/` is not affected by `$/`.

Without /m,

- `/^/` matches the starts of the string. (`/(?-m:^)/` ⇔ `/\A/`)
- `/$/` matches at the end of the string, and before a newline at the end of the string. (`/(?-m:$)/` ⇔ `/\Z/` ⇔ `/(?=\n\z)|\z/`)

```
^__Data__\n          "^" denotes where /(?-m:$)/ can match
This is test A.\n    "$" denotes where /(?-m:$)/ can match
This is test B.\n
This is test C.\n
This is test D.$\n$
```

With /m,

- `/^/` matches the starts of the string and after a "\n". (`/(?m:^)/` ⇔ `/\A|(?<=\n)/`)
- `/$/` matches before a newline and at the end of the string. (`/(?m:$)/` ⇔ `/(?=\n)|\z/`)

```
^__Data__$\n           "^" denotes where /(?m:^)/ can match
^This is test A.$\n    "$" denotes where /(?m:$)/ can match
^This is test B.$\n
^This is test C.$\n
^This is test D.$\n$
```

---

I was asked about

```
...$\n$
```

First, let's demonstrate:

```
>perl -E"say qq{abc\n} =~ /abc$/ ? 1 : 0"
1

>perl -E"say qq{abc\n} =~ /abc\n$/ ? 1 : 0"
1
```

The point is to allow `/^abc$/` to match both `"abc\n"` and `"abc"`.

```
>perl -E"say qq{abc\n} =~ /^abc$/ ? 1 : 0"
1

>perl -E"say qq{abc} =~ /^abc$/ ? 1 : 0"
1
```

Comment: I've been using perl for 15+ years, know what `m` does quite well, and your post baffles me. Plover boiled this down to one sentence 9 years ago: /m: Make ^ match at beginning of line (after a newline) rather than beginning of string, and similarly $ at the end. http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide068.html

Comment: very clear now, thanks ikegami but I don't understand ($\n$) This is test D.$\n$

Comment: @Mark, That's wrong. "$" can match elsewhere then at the end of the string, both with and without /m. And since the OP was asking about specifics...

Comment: @jbs, Added to my node to expand on $\n$.

Comment: @ikegami - fair enough on the end-of-string returns matching, it is an odd bit of DWIM. I still think using `(?-m:)` and other obscure regex to explain simpler regex is a weird choice and less than clear. He did ask for detail and depth tho so you were right to bury him in it. ;-)

Comment: @Mark, I independently defined `^` and `$` using both words and using code. Either stands on its own. If you don't want to deal with `(?-m:)`, you don't have to as its only in the mathematical definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct, multiline causes ^ and $ to match the beginning and end of the string, whereas without it you match between newlines (and string ends).